# Why does this work with MSVC but not with Mingw?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, g++

```
#define log(x) std::cout << x
using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
void print(optional<T> c) 
{ 
   log(c.value_or("Input was std::nullopt")); 
}

template<typename T1, typename... T2> 
void print(optional<T1> c, optional<T2...> cs) 
{ 
   log(c.value_or("Input was std::nullopt")); print(cs...); 
}

int main() {
    optional<string> val(nullopt);
    print(val);
    return 1;
}
```

On MSVC c++20 it works just fine but with g++ -std=c++2a it gives the following error:
**error: expansion pattern 'cs' contains no argument packs

void print(optional c, optional<T2...> cs) { log(c.value_or("Input was std::nullopt"));   print(cs...); }**

The error only happens if i pass a nullopt value in. If i would pass a normal string to the variable it would also work fine.

Comment: I would expect the uses of `optional` and of `std::cout` to give problems since neither of them is defined. Post real code, the smallest you can come up with that shows the problem.

Comment: Unrelated: `#define log(x) std::cout << x` makes things harder to compute a logarithm.

Comment: I'm surprised MSVC compiled this.  `cs` is not a parameter pack so g++ is correctly rejecting the code.  It looks like you want to accept an arbitrary number of optionals, which would need a syntax like `template<typename T1, typename... T2> void print(optional<T1> c, T2... cs)`.  You can use SFINAE or concepts to constrain `T2` to being optional types.

Comment: `optional<T2> ...cs` also works.